# EF6 Add-Migration for not nullable string?

Tags: entity-framework

I would add a NOT NULL NVARCHAR column by code first from below code:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required, MaxLength(10), MinLength(5)] 
    public string StaffCode { get; set; }
}
```

Then i run **"Add-Migration User"** on Nuget console,

It generate the migrate class below:

```
public partial class abc : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AlterColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "StaffCode", c => c.String(maxLength: 10));
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        AlterColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "StaffCode", c => c.String());
    }
}
```

The **minlength:5** and **nullable:false** is gone.
I call add it manually and update to database, but it seems not reasonable.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would answer my question.
i find that post:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/04/15/tip-12-choosing-an-inheritance-strategy.aspx

By default EF6 using **TPH** ,which not allow set the column to NOT NULL.
Please conside Table Per Type (TPT) or Table Per Concrete Class (TPC)